# Select a record based on translated name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

on ruby console when I do `Resource.all` it give me the following:

```
[<Resource id:'...', name_translated:{"en"=>'vehicle',"fr"=>'véhicule'}> ...]
```

How do I make a selection such that Resource.find_by_name_translated("vehicle")

Comment: It was easy to query database with serialized hash as value if you were using `PG`

Comment: Sorry, I am new to ruby, rails, and PG. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/hstore.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work, I think it's not the most efficient way though:

```
#app/models/resource.rb

def self.find_by_english_name(name)
  Resource.all.select do |resource|
    resource.name_translated['en'] == name
  end
end
```

if you want to be able to find by multiple languages (defaulting to english) with one method, try this:

```
def self.find_by_name(name, language = 'en')
  Resource.all.select do |resource|
    resource.name_translated[language] == name
  end
end
```

Since you're using Postgres this can also be written as follows:

```
def self.find_by_name(name, language = 'en')
  Resource.where("name_translated ->> '#{language}' = '#{name}'")
end
```

Comment: How do I improve this function: e.g. for two languages like en and fr I have to define `self.find_by_en_name` and `self.find_by_fr_name`. Is there a way to DRY up this code. Thank you

Comment: you could pass in the language as well - i'll update my answer

Comment: i didn't realize you were using postgres, i'll add another option to my answer :D

Comment: I still like this solution but if you think you have a better solution then please update the answer.

Comment: Third solution gives me an error
`SELECT "resource".* FROM "resource" WHERE (name_translated ->> 'en' = light vehicles)

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near “vehicles"

LINE 1: …resource" WHERE (name_translated ->> 'en' = light vehicles)`

Comment: ah, i think i see the mistake, name needs to be in quotes, updated now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92739/discussion-between-akadisoft-and-dax).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use regex query if your db doesn't allow to query by json fields:

```
Resource.where("name_translated LIKE '#{translated_name}%'")
```

Comment: how do you handle the situation when there is another record like `non vehicle`?

Comment: not working for me when I try `Resource.where("name_translated LIKE %#{vehicle}%")`. I am getting StatementInvalid ... PG::SyntaxError

Comment: @Akadisoft, just updated the answer for PG (only one `%`)

Comment: @illusionist, maybe include quotes?

Comment: I am trying `Resource.where("name_translated LIKE #{'light vehicles'}%")` but I am still getting the error

Comment: @Akadisoft, as far as you use PG, then I'd stick to dax's answer